# Clipping Voronoi vessels (pysal.cg.voronoi)

Tags: python, voronoi, pysal

straight to the problem: given these points

[[ 77.51 254.19], [ 75.32 184.45], [ 88.57  83.43], [153.   135.  ], [196.62  55.78]]

and a polygon that defines the bounding box, which should be covered entirely by voronoi tessels: [230 0; 230 370; 0 370; 0 0; 230 0]

I use this code to perform Voronoi tessellation:

```
from libpysal.cg.voronoi  import voronoi, voronoi_frames

points = np.array(self.__get_coordinates())
bb = box(self.min_x, self.min_y, self.max_x, self.max_y)
region_df, point_df = voronoi_frames(points, clip=bb)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(*bb.exterior.xy,lw=3)
region_df.plot(ax=ax, color='white', edgecolor='black', lw=3)
point_df.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
```

where min_x=0,min_y=0,max_x=230,max_y=370. Unfortunately I obtain this result

[image]

which is not correct as the upper polygon do not cover the remaining part of the bounding box.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please report it to https://github.com/pysal/libpysal/issues? This is clearly a bug.